# How to peek recently sent messages into Service bus queue?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am sending messages from my custom application to servicebus. And recently I have added some messages for testing purposes. But later I realized that I have picked the wrong Queue. Now I don't want the Test messages to be in this queue. Is there any possible way to delete those recently added test messages from my queue?

Comment: Yes you can. https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/service-bus-messaging/explorer

Comment: Very useful tool: https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Pedro in his comment you can use service bus explorer: https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer to peek and delete the message from the queue. Alternatively, you can call the service bus REST API or write your own code to consume that message.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use [Service Bus Cloud Explorer](https://cloudbricks.io/products/service_bus_cloud_explorer/) which runs in the browser with logged-in user Azure account by default and have a delete and a purge functionality.

[image]

Keep in mind that it will take time to clear up queues or subscriptions. More messages it needs to delete; the more time it would take.